# Increased performance from single statement, multiple row inserts?

Tags: postgresql, performance, bulk-insert

I'm currently [obsessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025018/variable-length-of-parameters-passed-to-libpqxx-prepared-statement) over bulk inserts via prepared statements with libpqxx.

I am far from a database expert and even further when it comes to Postgres, but just thinking superficially, it doesn't seem like it would make a difference.

In my MySQL days, it made a huge difference, but it strikes me that MySQL's clustered index was the bottleneck, that it would be better to prepare it for many rows at once rather than one at a time.

Since Postgres doesn't do that, happily I might add, is it correct that there would be a near negligible performance boost to bulk inserts?  Please explain why or why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *big* difference. Insert as many rows as possible at once. Best in a single [`INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) statement, but at least in a single transaction. Inserting individual rows takes much longer. Quoting the chapter [**Populating a Database**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html):

> If you allow each insertion to be committed separately, PostgreSQL is
>   doing a lot of work for each row that is added. An additional benefit
>   of doing all insertions in one transaction is that if the insertion of
>   one row were to fail then the insertion of all rows inserted up to
>   that point would be rolled back, so you won't be stuck with partially
>   loaded data.

If you insert a large number of rows, consider [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html), which is much faster, yet. And read that chapter in the manual. It has all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. TWhat considers as large number of rows?

Comment: @user: That depends on many factors. Row size, DB setup, connection, etc. You'll have to test to find your sweet spot. If in doubt, `COPY` (or the corresponding `\copy` meta-command of psql) is almost always fastest. `INSERT` is mostly for operations *within* the database.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything equivalent if I am trying ot insert large volume of data from python?

Comment: @user: I am no Python expert. But from what I remember, Python has [`copy_from`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) to make use of this. A quick search based on this turned up this [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30050097/939860) and  this [related blog post](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql). For anything more, please create a new *question*. Comments are not the place.