# Delete index while query is running, is it possible?

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, insert, postgresql-9.4

I am currently importing Wikipedia pagelinks in my postgres database, and it takes forever (three days and still running). Is it possible to drop the primary key index while the inserts are still running, and would this speed things up?

Actually, if this changes anything, it is a uniqueness constraint over three columns that creates the index.

Comment: It's best to tag [postgres] as well. Many only subscribe to the main tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Yes*, a plain `INSERT` is fastest when no indexes have to be maintained. So it may pay to drop indexes before huge bulk inserts and add them later. Depends on the whole situation, of course.

*No*, you cannot drop a PK or a UNIQUE constraint or even a plain index in the middle of an `INSERT`, which also writes to the index.

*No*, I don't think your query should take more than three days, even if you import every link that every Wikipedia site on earth ever had to offer. There is probably something less than ideal in your command or setup or hardware or how you read / write the data.
For starters, an operation of that magnitude would rather use `COPY`:

- [Increased performance from single statement, multiple row inserts?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63055/increased-performance-from-single-statement-multiple-row-inserts/63066#63066)

Comment: I deleted the constraint, and the insert sped up a lot. Since these are lots of single inserts, I think, the drop did work. Now, you say I can't drop it in the middle of a single INSERT, what about a transaction with many inserts, is the index also part of the transaction environment?

Comment: @kutschkem: The index is "part of the transaction", but locks don't block statements *inside* the same transaction. So it wouldn't be a problem to `DROP` (or `CREATE`) the index *between* statements inside a single transaction. Concerning *single inserts*: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63055/increased-performance-from-single-statement-multiple-row-inserts/63066#63066